# What's new with GDR-3?

Tags: 8.0, gdr-3

What are the new features provided by Microsoft Windows Phone 8's upcoming update gdr-3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[New standard features](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/10/14/announcing-our-third-windows-phone-8-update-plus-a-new-developer-preview-program.aspx) users can use immediately.

- **Driving Mode** A new feature called Driving Mode helps you get from point A to point B with fewer distractions. Working with a connected Bluetooth device, Driving Mode is designed to limit notifications on the lock screen—including texts, calls, and quick status alerts—until you’re safely parked.
- **New accessibility features** Another highlight of the new update is Mobile Accessibility for Windows Phone 8, which isn’t a single feature but a suite of apps designed to make Windows Phone easier to see, hear, and use. The apps, which include a screen reader, make it easier for blind and visually impaired users to manage calls and contacts, send texts and emails, browse the web, make Skype and Lync calls, and hear notifications like alarms, calendar events, and low-battery warnings.
- **More useful ringtones:** With Update 3, you can use custom ringtones for more things—including instant messages, emails, voicemails, and reminders. You can also assign custom ringtones to contacts for text messages, so you'll know who's texting you without even looking.
- **No more twist and shout:** Does your screen keep spinning when you’re trying to read emails in bed? Use the new rotation lock option to keep it fixed in place.
- **Better storage management:** New storage settings make it easier to free up space on your phone and manage temporary files. A new category view shows what's taking up space at a glance.
- **Easily close apps:** Now you can use the App switcher to quickly close apps when you're finished with them.
- **Wi-Fi access out of the box:** You can now connect to Wi-Fi during phone set up, so you can start conserving cellular data right out of the box.
- **Better Bluetooth:** The team made a bunch of improvements to improve connection quality for Bluetooth accessories.

Also, Microsoft has released the [following list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_wp8_gdr3) as the new and changed features app developers can take advantage of in Update 3.

- **Support for devices with 1080p display resolution.** For more info, see Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8.
- **Increased memory cap for apps.** On 2-GB phones, the maximum memory available for apps that have Windows Phone 8 Update 3 is 570 MB. For more info about memory caps, see App memory limits for Windows Phone 8.
- **Increased memory cap for background audio apps.** On devices that have 1 GB of memory, the memory cap for background audio apps has increased from 20 MB to 25 MB. For more info about background audio apps, see Background audio overview for Windows Phone.
- **New Uri schemes for additional settings.** There are new Uri schemes to display the Battery Saver settings page or the Screen Rotation settings page. (The Screen Rotation settings page is also new in Windows Phone 8 Update 3.) For more info, see URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8.
- **Additional use of app icon.** In the task switcher, the app icon and app title are now displayed along with the screenshot of the last active page of the app.
- **Custom sounds for toast notifications.** You can now use reflection to specify custom sounds for toast notifications. For more info, see Toasts for Windows Phone.
- **New property related to push notifications.** A new Boolean property is available through reflection. The new property indicates whether battery saving mode is turned on. It complements the existing PowerSavingMode property, which indicates whether battery saving mode is active. When PowerSavingModeEnabled is true, an app can warn users that push notifications are not received. For more info, see Setting up your app to receive push notifications for Windows Phone.
- **Changed behavior of device-width.** The behavior of device-width when used with viewport settings has changed in the WebBrowser control and in Internet Explorer. For more info, see Web development for Windows Phone.
- **Changed behavior of toast notifications.** Toast notifications are now displayed when the target app is running in the foreground but is obscured by other activity such as a phone call or the lock screen. Previously, toast notifications were not displayed when the target app was running in the foreground, even when the app was obscured.

Comment: Most of them are from the [link](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/10/14/announcing-our-third-windows-phone-8-update-plus-a-new-developer-preview-program.aspx) I provided. Thanks anyway for the extra informations.

Comment: One of the reasons I placed additional details in my answer is that links die. And unfortunately, Microsoft's technical documentation links tend not to last too long. I feel its important to point to the source and bring the material over to a more stable location.

Answer (score 2):

Following are the key features,

- Support for bigger, higher-resolution screens
- Driving Mode
- New accessibility features
- Improved Internet Sharing
- Custom ringtones
- Rotation lock
- App switcher

For more information check [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/10/14/announcing-our-third-windows-phone-8-update-plus-a-new-developer-preview-program.aspx).